# Which version of Oracle is suitable for Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, install, software

I just bought my Mac few days ago and I am trying to install Oracle Express for work purpose on Mac OSX X 10.7.1.

I've downloaded Oracle 10g R2 from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/10204macsoft-x86-64-092720.html) but when I run the installation shortcut,I got the following messages

```
No pre-requisite checks found in oraparam.ini, no system pre-requisite
checks will be executed.
Preparing to launch Oracle Universal Installer from /tmp/OraInstall2011-10-13_02-58-18PM.
Please wait ...
tokwan:~ tokwan$ java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /private/tmp/OraInstall2011-10-13_02-58-18PM/oui/lib/mac_osx/liboraInstaller.dylib:
no suitable image found.  
Did find:  /private/tmp/OraInstall2011-10-13_02-58-18PM/oui/lib/mac_osx/liboraInstaller.dylib: mach-o, 
but wrong architecture
```

I did try to check the pre-requisite from [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b25286/pre_install.htm#BABIBGFA).but I'm not sure if I am following the right guide because some of the instruction and output are differ from what it suggested.

I am fairly new to Mac, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Just to be sure: this is **not** Oracle XE (which is only available for Linux or Windows)

Comment: @Matteo Oracle XE not on Mac?I didn't know and didn't notice that.I guess the only solution is to install VM and install Oracle on it.

Comment: Yes, I don't really get Oracle strategy since the non-XE version is available. We are using a Linux VM with VirtualBox for development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Oracle DB is certified for Lion. In fact no Oracle DB is certified for Snow Leopard either. So don't expect official Oracle's support on this.

For unofficial ways to do it, see this SuperUser question: [OS X Lion and installing Oracle 10G](https://superuser.com/questions/313297/os-x-lion-installing-oracle-10g-standard-edition)